# Ansible : 'NetworkManagementClient' object has no attribute 'private_endpoints'

Tags: ansible, azure, python

I try to deploy a private endpoint for a storage account with **Ansible**. I am using [azure.azcollection.azure_rm_privateendpoint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_privateendpoint_module.html#requirements). My playbook code is as below:

```
- name: Create PE
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

    - name: create_pe
      azure.azcollection.azure_rm_privateendpoint:
        name: testprivateendpoint
        resource_group: MYRG
        private_link_service_connections:
          - name: pe-satest
            group_ids: blob
            private_link_service_id: /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/MYRG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mysa
        subnet:
          id: /subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/MYRG-VNET/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/MYVNET/subnets/mySubnet
```

After launching the ansible-playbook command, i have the error below:

```
TASK [create_pe] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error creating or updating private endpoint testprivateendpoint - 'NetworkManagementClient' object has no attribute 'private_endpoints'"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- The private endpoint **can be created manually** from the Azure portal with the
  same properties.
- The subnet's private endpoint network policies
  were    already **disabled**.
- My initial Ansible version was **2.9**. After the error, I have updated it to **Ansible 4.6** but i still get the same error.
- My OS is RHEL 8.4.
- Python 3.6

Any ideas about the source of this error?